# why scriptpubkey is different

Tags: transactions, script, public-key

I am confused when i see this transaction

[Test transaction with one input and two outputs](https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/address/mvnWTMe8Wzx7RcXP5cZnFNBc83FLoiMwyP)

Since scriptpubkey verifies the hash of the sender's public key and sender's signature, i am wondering why the two scriptpubkeys are different. Shouldn't they be the same? I am saying the XXX part in the following should be identical

OP_DUP OP_HASH160 XXX OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG

If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scriptpubkey is the locking script, it contains the condition to spend this output, so XXX is the hash referent to the address that is receiving, that´s why is different.